# Blocking non-secure http request with service worker

Tags: javascript, security, https, service-worker

I'm migrating a website to https, but our ad delivery network often sends non-secure ads via http resulting in "mixed content" warning. Is it a good idea to block/stub all http requests with a service worker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSP to block all non-https requests:

`Content-Security-Policy: block-all-mixed-content`

It will rewrite http requests into https. If you just want to block them, something like that should work :

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https:;`

More details: https://scotthelme.co.uk/migrating-from-http-to-https-ease-the-pain-with-csp-and-hsts/

https://report-uri.io/home/generate
(I think it's better than using a service worker for that...)

WARNING: If misuse, CSP can block legitimate requests and/or inline scripts/css/plugins...

Comment: Thanks a lots, I didn't know about this header, exactly what I was looking for ! It also have a better browser support than service worker, perfect :)

Comment: @RomainDurand WARNING : If misuse it may block others requests or inline scripts!